# Android Billing Subscription will not automatically renew

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I am integrating the billing v3 subscription for my app, and billing client showing as This subscription will not automatically renew. I need it should be renew automatically.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Play is suspending free trials in India following new RBI regulations.

Please refer to this [link](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-suspend-free-trials-auto-renewing-subscriptions/)